# Why does it display the error: "Resource leak: 'keyboard' is never closed"?

Tags: java, eclipse, input, java.util.scanner

I recently installed Eclipse on a new computer and when I tried to write this code it gave me this error. I swear that I've written this type of

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in)
```

many of times in my old computer and have never gotten this error until now.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class W1M1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hellow World");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); //'keyboard' word shows this error
    System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
    String userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Hello there, " + userInput + ".");
}

}
```

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning. This warning, in this specific context (that it's a scanner reading from `System.in`), can be ignored.

Comment: why is it a warning though? And how do I turn it off?

Comment: You’ve opened a `Scanner`, but never explicitly closed it.  Add `keyboard.close()`, or better, use try-with-resources to automatically close it.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class implements the [`Closable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) interface - i.e., it opens a resource, and you should call the [`close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) method yourself, so, generally speaking, Eclipse does the right thing and produces a warning here.

However, in this specific case, `keyboard` is a `Scanner` that refers to `System.in` - the standard input descriptor. You should never close this yourself, and should just suppress Eclipse's warning in this case.